# Get Product API and Facing this error on swagger, Error: response status is 401

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

```
**Requested URL :** https://localhost:7028/api/Products?Authorization=bearer%20eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjBERTk0RjhGQzBBRkM4RkIxMUYyQzFDMEE4QTRCNzdGIiwidHlwIjoiYXQrand0In0.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.OLVlAdSe8CEzX_W5KmwqJIyvnbPvZPuhDRALN95FeHo-cKUO8b4L_ARq8kYOQPj3XVvCNDuLcQQToh5XIebzJuJDuSE27XwKIclXFIAmkjkoAxH07KAObBF5Tpp52qEDqM7B1oSWvr4UW-HrnR_NR1ojvsjtosh-y69boKVXdoRBThS1xuSepItWmWYgznItprQcJKQxUt1RXOYsrFUN_FvXtUqlNV2noDka6OAMjLe9OkB6IKa8sdciTa9NAc8RHe5yRHSaNdzIOEce9ood7joRU9ZJkShJlQ-NxwmXgnpNFXAQDqgmeLHVn1WM6YTkzf8Dm3rn9XKLAUk8quKuZQ


**Program.cs** file of **quickbite.Services.ProductAPI**
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using QuickBite.Services.ProductAPI;
using QuickBite.Services.ProductAPI.DbContexts;
using QuickBite.Services.ProductAPI.Repository;
using System.Text;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
    builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
    ));
#region mapping
IMapper mapper = MappingConfig.RegisterMapConfig().CreateMapper();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(mapper);
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
#endregion
builder.Services.AddScoped<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// add Authentication bearer for identity token

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.Authority = "https://localhost:7270/"; //URL of identity Server
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
        };
    });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("ApiScope", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policy.RequireClaim("scope", "quickbite");
    });
});

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "QuickBite.Services.ProductAPI", Version = "v1" });

    // Add Bearer token security definition
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Description = @"Enter Bearer [Space] and your token",
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        Scheme = "Bearer"
    });

    // Add Bearer token security requirement
    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = "Bearer"
                },
                Scheme = "oauth2",
                Name = "Bearer",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header
            },
            new List<string>()
        }
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();


**Program.cs** file of **quickbite.Web**
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using QuickBite.Web;
using QuickBite.Web.Services;
using QuickBite.Web.Services.IServices;
using System.Configuration;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation(); 
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IProductService,ProductService>();
SD.ProductAPI = builder.Configuration["MicroServiceUrl:ProductAPI"];
builder.Services.AddScoped<IProductService,ProductService>();


//Here, we adding authentication with identity server (OpenIdConnect, Scope, client etc)
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
        options.LoginPath = "/Auth/Login";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Auth/AccessDenied";
        options.LogoutPath = "/Auth/Logout";
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = builder.Configuration["MicroServiceUrl:IdentityAPI"];
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.ClientId = "quickbite";
        options.ClientSecret = "secret";
        options.ResponseType = "code";
        options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
        options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";
        options.Scope.Add("quickbite");
        options.SaveTokens=true;
        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            OnRemoteFailure= context =>
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/");
                context.HandleResponse();
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        };
    });

/////////////////
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader();
    });
});
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.UseCors("AllowAll");
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

I have three project which are

- quickbite.Web
- quickbite.Services.ProductAPI
- quickbite.Services.IdentityServer
  When these projects are executing then I take the access_token from web project and manually using it on swagger, but facing this error, which is showing in Screenshot which i placed as well.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnscl.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seFIq.png) . I want to access these Products.

Comment: What I can find the issue is you are using wrong middleware order,[ you should Enable CORS before UseAuthentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#middleware-order). And you also could use [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) to decode the token and check the details.

Comment: By the way, pls check the servers's time, make sure the time is same, I also faced this kind of issue before, the token was expired once generated due the the wrong server time.